# Fit text to linewidth, shrinking only

Tags: graphics, scaling

I often have AVMs/tables that are just a bit too large and use `\resizebox` to fit everything in one line. Now, if the `linewidth` changes (switch from `twocolumn` to `onecolumn`) this results in enlarging the text.

```
\newcommand{\oneline}[1]{\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{#1}}
```

Is there some way to reach the same result but without the possibility of enlarging the box?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following example puts the contents in a box (this is done by `\resizebox` anyway), measures the width and applies `\resizebox` if necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\restrictlinewidthbox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd0>\linewidth
      \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\copy0}%
    \else
      \copy0 %
    \fi
  \endgroup
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\restrictlinewidthbox{\rule{10mm}{10mm}}

\restrictlinewidthbox{\rule{2\linewidth}{10mm}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

[David Carlisle's trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136629/16967)

```
\resizebox{\ifdim\width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\width\fi}{!}{\rule{10mm}{10mm}}
```

also applies the resizing, if the natural `\width` is used. For example, the result in this case with `pdflatex` is a scaling factor of `1.00005` instead of `1`.

### Rounding errors of `\resizebox`

The calculations of `\resizebox` are not too precise. Especially the box can be a little larger than specified. The following variant contributes the rounding error to the left and right of the box:

```
\newcommand{\restrictlinewidthbox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{\ignorespaces#1\unskip}%
    \leavevmode
    \ifdim\wd0>\linewidth
      \hbox to\linewidth{%
        \hss\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\copy0 }\hss
      }%
    \else
      \copy0 %
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
```

See [question "Vertical space in interaction with figure/center environment"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136644/16967)
and [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136678/16967) there.

Answer (score 6):

```
\resizebox{\ifdim\width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\width\fi}{!}{#1}}
```

probably works

Comment: for my use, this worked better than the accepted answer (I don't fully understand why; the sbox in the other answer seemed to be causing problems)

Answer (score 5):

Use `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox}

\newcommand*{\restrictlinewidthbox}[1]{%
  \adjustbox{max width=\linewidth}{#1}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\restrictlinewidthbox{\rule{10mm}{10mm}}

\restrictlinewidthbox{\rule{2\linewidth}{10mm}}

\end{document}
```

(For the picture, I added the frame lines with `geometry`, not shown in the source.)

[image]

You can, of course, use `\adjustbox` directly or in its environment form:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\linewidth}
<material>
\end{adjustbox}
```