# Vertical space in interaction with figure/center environment

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I misused the `figure` environment to insert some vertical space and now try to replace it by `center`. However, the two environments behave differently when I use a scaled box as content of the `figure`/`center` environment. `center` inserts more space. Is there a way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}          

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\oneline}[1]{\resizebox{\ifdim\width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\width\fi}{!}{#1}}

\begin{document}               

\lipsum 
\lipsum[3-8]  

%\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[H]
\oneline{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  Prefield & T/C & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Sentence Field} \\ \hline
& & & Verbal Field & \\ \hline\hline
Om andre bisper \ldots & vides & ikke & & \\
(`whether other bishops ) & (`know.{\sc pres.pass}') & (`not') &&\\\hline
& om &  andre bisper& har & lignende planer \\
& (`whether') &  (`other bishops') & (`have) & (`similar plans') \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{figure}
%\end{center}

\lipsum[3-10]  

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can put the content inside a group and use `\centering` inside that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is a rounding error of `\resizebox`. If `\hfuzz` is set to `0pt`, then all overfull `\hbox` warnings are generated:

```
Overfull \hbox (0.0093pt too wide) in paragraph at lines ...
```

Then you get an empty line and the overfull `\hbox` is moved to the next line causing more empty space above the table.

The following definition of `\oneline` contributes the rounding error equally to the left and right. Also it removes spaces before and after the contents, because the example in the question has an additional space after `\end{tabular}` because of the line end.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\oneline}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{\ignorespaces#1\unskip}%
    \leavevmode
    \ifdim\wd0>\linewidth
      \hbox to\linewidth{%
        \hss\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\copy0 }\hss
      }%
    \else
      \copy0 %
    \fi
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{center}
\oneline{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  Prefield & T/C & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Sentence Field} \\ \hline
& & & Verbal Field & \\ \hline\hline
Om andre bisper \ldots & vides & ikke & & \\
(`whether other bishops ) & (`know.{\sc pres.pass}') & (`not') &&\\\hline
& om &  andre bisper& har & lignende planer \\
& (`whether') &  (`other bishops') & (`have) & (`similar plans') \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solves and explains a lot of other problems too. In draft mode I often saw black boxes, which did not make any sense to me. But this was probably also due to the rounding errors.