# Shrinking verbatim text

Tags: graphics, verbatim, scaling

Heiko Oberdiek helped me a lot by finding a solution for [shrinking text when needed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136625/fit-text-to-linewidth-shrinking-only/). I want to apply this method to verbatim text as in the example below, but this is somehow forbidden (Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.). Is there another way to shrink `verbatim` text to fit the `\linewidth`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\restrictlinewidthbox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd0>\linewidth
      \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\copy0}%
    \else
      \copy0 %
    \fi
  \endgroup
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\restrictlinewidthbox{%
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{tabular}
       {|lc|c|c|c|}\hline   
      & \textbf{Input}  & Cnstrnt 1  &  Cnstrnt 2& Cnstrnt 3\\ \hline\hline
      & candidate 1     & *!         &           &          \\ \hline
      & candidate 2     &            &  *        &          \\ \hline
\hand & candidate 3     &            &           &  *       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{verbatim}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: verbatim can not go in macro argument: you need to use the lrbox environment rather than sbox.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to replace `sbox` by `lrbox`, but xelatex was not happy with this.

Comment: @StefanMüller: It's important to use a environment instead of a command with a mandatory argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an environment for this. You can use `fancyvrb` and its facilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{restrictlinewidthverb}
 {\SaveVerbatim{rlwv}}
 {\endSaveVerbatim
  \sbox0{\BUseVerbatim{rlwv}}
  \begingroup\center % don't add indentation
  \ifdim\wd0>\linewidth
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\copy0}%
  \else
    \copy0
  \fi
  \endcenter\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{restrictlinewidthverb}
\begin{tabular}
       {|lc|c|c|c|}\hline   
      & \textbf{Input}  & Cnstrnt 1  &  Cnstrnt 2& Cnstrnt 3\\ \hline\hline
      & candidate 1     & *!         &           &          \\ \hline
      & candidate 2     &            &  *        &          \\ \hline
\hand & candidate 3     &            &           &  *       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{restrictlinewidthverb}

\begin{restrictlinewidthverb}
Abc
def
\end{restrictlinewidthverb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is only an example, of course: double `\hline` commands and worksheet-like tables are *evil*: don't use vertical rules in your tables and your life will be better. `;-)`.

Comment: Ehm, this is what other researchers do who work in the framework of Optimality Theory. I just try to make their life better by making their books look better ...

Answer (score 2):

The `verbatimbox` package allows you to stuff the verbatim into a box, and then you can resize the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\newcommand*{\restrictlinewidthbox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd0>\linewidth
      \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\copy0}%
    \else
      \copy0 %
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\rule{\textwidth}{1ex}
\begin{verbbox}
\begin{tabular}
       {|lc|c|c|c|}\hline   
      & \textbf{Input}  & Cnstrnt 1  &  Cnstrnt 2& Cnstrnt 3\\ \hline\hline
      & candidate 1     & *!         &           &          \\ \hline
      & candidate 2     &            &  *        &          \\ \hline
\hand & candidate 3     &            &           &  *       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{verbbox}
\restrictlinewidthbox{\theverbbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]